# Duplicate data from select statement

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to make a stress test to a procedure than generate a .csv file.
The problem is that i have not enough data, so i want to duplicate data in my sql select .

The query look like this:

```
SELECT P.FST_NAME,
           P.LAST_NAME,
           P.EMAIL_ADDR,
           P.PERSON_UID,
           PR.FST_NAME PRSP_FST_NAME,
           PR.LAST_NAME PRSP_LAST_NAME, 
           M.X_BAPRO_DT_01,
           M.X_BAPRO_DT_02,
           M.X_BAPRO_DT_03,
           M.X_BAPRO_MONTO,
           M.X_BAPRO_NUM_01,
           M.X_BAPRO_NUM_02,
           M.X_BAPRO_NUM_03,
           M.X_BAPRO_TEXT_01,
           M.X_BAPRO_TEXT_02,
           M.X_BAPRO_TEXT_03,
           M.X_BAPRO_TEXT_04,
           M.X_BAPRO_TEXT_05
    FROM SIEBEL.S_SRC C 
    left join SIEBEL.S_CAMP_CON M on C.ROW_ID = M.SRC_ID
    left join SIEBEL.S_DMND_CRTN_PRG T on T.ROW_ID = M.DCP_ID
    left join SIEBEL.S_CONTACT P on P.ROW_ID = M.CON_PER_ID
    left join SIEBEL.S_PRSP_CONTACT PR on PR.ROW_ID= M.PRSP_CON_PER_ID 
    WHERE 
      C.ROW_ID <> p_row_id
```

So, This query return about 100 records, i want to retrive 1000 records and i dont really care if the data is duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `cross join`:

```
FROM SIEBEL.S_SRC C 
    left join SIEBEL.S_CAMP_CON M on C.ROW_ID = M.SRC_ID
    left join SIEBEL.S_DMND_CRTN_PRG T on T.ROW_ID = M.DCP_ID
    left join SIEBEL.S_CONTACT P on P.ROW_ID = M.CON_PER_ID
    left join SIEBEL.S_PRSP_CONTACT PR on PR.ROW_ID= M.PRSP_CON_PER_ID 
    cross join (select 1 as n from dual union all
                select 2 from dual
                . . .
               ) x
```

Comment: Could it be that you need to leave out the `from dual` part in your subuery?

Comment: it works like a charm, to add an improvement, repeating (n times) ` CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 2 FROM DUAL) ` makes the addition of data exponential.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `VALUE` clause to construct the little "muliplier"-table as shown below:

```
SELECT ...
FROM SIEBEL.S_SRC C 
left join SIEBEL.S_CAMP_CON M on C.ROW_ID = M.SRC_ID
left join SIEBEL.S_DMND_CRTN_PRG T on T.ROW_ID = M.DCP_ID
left join SIEBEL.S_CONTACT P on P.ROW_ID = M.CON_PER_ID
left join SIEBEL.S_PRSP_CONTACT PR on PR.ROW_ID= M.PRSP_CON_PER_ID 
cross join (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) tabl(n)
```